# Asynchronously iterate over all Room records only once

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to perform an asynchonous operation on each record in a large Room table.

I thought I could add a method returning [Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html) in my DAO like this:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM events")
    fun getEvents(): Flow<EventEntity>
```

But according to [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-flow-273acffe5b57) and [this documentation page](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-flow) returning a Flow is making an "observable read" so the Flow never completes and it watches for database changes.

My goal is to iterate over all the entities only **once**. I don't want the "observability" behavior. Also, since the table is very large, I don't want to load all the records into a List at once in order to avoid consuming too much memory.

Could you recommend some solution, please?

Comment: I'm looking for something similar.  I just want an Iterator<T> stream.  There is the new Pagination stuff, but that's a bit of sledge hammer.  There is also a true Cursor, but that has warts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new method that does not use `Flow.`

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM events")
fun getAllIds(): List<Int> // If your primary key is Integer.

@Query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = :id")
fun getById(id: Int): EventEntity?
```

Use Kotlin coroutines to call this method on IO thread.

There could be several strategies to load one row at a time. This is the simplest - get all ids and load each item one at a time.

```
suspend fun getEvents() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // Get entities from database on IO thread.
        val ids = dao.getAllIds()
        ids.forEach { id ->
             val event = dao.getById(id)
        }
    }
}
```

### Pagination based approach

This approach assumes that you have a column that stores timestamp (eg. `created_at`).

```
@Query("SELECT * from events WHERE created_at > :timestamp ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 10")
fun getAfter(timestamp: Long): List<EventEntity>
```

You can use this method to paginate.

```
suspend fun getEvents() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        var timestamp: Long = 0
        while (true) {
          // Get entities from database on IO thread.
          val events = dao.getAfter(timestamp)

          // Process this batch of events

          // Get timestamp for pagination offset.
          timestamp = events.maxBy { it.createAt }?.createAt ?: -1

          if (timestamp == -1) {
             // break the loop. This will be -1 only if the list of events are empty.
          }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my question I wrote I don't want to load all the records into a List at once in order to avoid consuming too much memory. Your solution seems to load all of them at once.

Comment: Is it the only valid option? To load all the IDs? I undestand loading only the IDs should be better than loading all the table at once, which I wanted to avoid, but honestly I was looking for a solution similar to paging or something more sophisticated.

Comment: @AndrzejZabost Can't give you a proper answer with paging if I don't know the db structure.

Comment: You can explain the idea briefly if you have one, I don't need the exact step-by-step solution. Would you recommend writing a custom DataSource.Factory or PagedList reader?

Comment: @AndrzejZabost Updated my answer. You can paginate if you have a column that you can properly order with.

Comment: Interesting solution. Thank you. I will mark your answer as accepted at least until there is some better idea.